# FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Im trying to upload file from a JSP file and I get the following error in catalina.out. As specified in many blogs, I increased the the max-file-size  under webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml but still I have the same problem...Where should I increase it to resolve this error?

```
<multipart-config>
      <!-- 50MB max -->
      <max-file-size>5242880000000</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>5242880000000</max-request-size>
      <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>

org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (341297) exceeds the configured maximum (51200)
```

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem. I solved it by setting the parameter `maxPostSize` in the http server tomcat connector located in `<tomcat-root-folder>/conf/server.xml` as follows:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" 
           port="8080" 
           protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           redirectPort="8443" 
           maxPostSize="52428800" />
```

Set `maxPostSize` to `52428800` increase the upload file size to `50 MB`. By default it's set to `2 MB`.

For more explanation, read this: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Answer (score 13):

https://maxrohde.com/2011/04/27/large-war-file-cannot-be-deployed-in-tomcat-7/

Go to the web.xml of the manager application (for instance it could be under /tomcat7/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml.
Increase the max-file-size and max-request-size:

```
<multipart-config>
<!– 50MB max –>
<max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
<max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
<file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is configured in `web.xml` for the manager app.

Ex:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HTMLManager</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <multipart-config>
      <!-- 50MB max -->
      <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
      <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
  </servlet>
```

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/7.0.x/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml#L56-L57

The manager app uses the Servlet 3.0 API.  If you're using commons file upload directly, it's up to you and you need to configure this manually.

Comment: find _webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml_, edit `max-file-size` and `max-request-size` to anything you need.

Comment: The Url is Broken

Comment: Fixed URL. Thanks

Comment: What do you do when `webapps/manager` doesn't exist?

Comment: The question was asked in reference to the Manager application that comes with Tomcat, so the instructions are to update the max allowed size in the web.xml for the manager app. If you're seeing this issue in a different app, then adjust the web.xml for your app. If you do not have a web.xml, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65473679/1585136.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Spring MultipartResolver](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload), find the bean and change it's maxUploadSize property.

```
`<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
   <property name="maxUploadSize" value="52428800" />
 </bean>`
```

Given code sets the upload file size to `50 MB`

Answer (score 0):

**you can use in Servlet like bellow**

```
    @WebServlet(name = "RemittanceDocApi", urlPatterns = {"/RemittanceDocApi"})
    @MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 2, // 2MB
    maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10, // 10MB
    maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50)   // 50MB
    public class RemittanceDocApi extends HttpServlet {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get hit limit from a spring microservice (internally tomcat, but no web.xml):

Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (26025118) exceeds the configured maximum (25165824)

Apply for microservice launch parameters (500MB upload per file limit):

```
  -spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=500MB
  -spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=500MB
```