# How Can I import larger dataset to mobiledata service of Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to import my dataset to mobiledata service through Mobiledata import function, however I am getting this error: {"message":"There is an exception while uploading file:

> [org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException:
>   the request was rejected because its size (174693558) exceeds the
>   configured maximum (104857600)]","code":20004}

Are there other ways to import larger datasets?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in following ways :

```
1: Try to increase  max-file-size & max-request-size 
2: Or best approach would to break the file in chunks and then try. In this approach you would never    have to bother about  max-file-size & max-request-size and also the process would be faster. There are many algorithms to break files in chunks and join them at target.
```

This link can help you :

https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/mbaas-api/#!/data/inject_post_0

Answer (score 0):

you may need to change the entries like max-file-size & max-request-size of web.xml.

Below is the reference link for the same:

```
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201102.mbox/%3Cloom.20110203T214804-280@post.gmane.org%3E
```

Apart from that you can use node.js sdk framework in Bluemix and upload data:

http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/node#mobile-data

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems related to web.xml,below is the similar issue reported on this forum:

[FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException apache tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774972/fileuploadbasesizelimitexceededexception-apache-tomcat)